# If/Else in shell script throws errors in Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Here's an example simple shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ 1 == 1 ]; then
echo "Something"
fi
```

When I run this

```
sh ./test.sh
```

I get:

```
./test.sh: 4: ./test.sh: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

It doesn't seem to recognize the 'then' I have in there. Any clue as to why? This is Ubuntu for Windows in case that part matters.

Running shell scripts in general is not a problem, it just seems to struggle with if/else.

Comment: 'test' is just the name of my script file, I'm not actually using a test command. This is just a really simple shell script. I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by WSL.

Comment: `[` **is** the `test` command, this has nothing to do with your script's file name. WSL is the “Windows Subsystem for Linux” I suppose you're talking about here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/commandline/wsl/about

Comment: Correct, that's what I'm using

Comment: Add the output of `sh -x ./test.sh` and `type -a sh`, please

Comment: Btw, quick question. Are you using greek keyboard by any chance ?

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems here. First, while you have a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) calling bash, you are executing the script as `sh script.sh`. The shebang line already specifies an interpreter for this script. So, just make the script executable:

```
chmod a+x ./test.sh
```

And then run it:

```
./test.sh
```

Alternatively, run it with bash explicitly:

```
bash ./test.sh
```

That will make it run with `bash` instead of `sh` which is a more limited shell and doesn't understand `==`. Which brings us to the second problem and why this fails. Strangely enough, you want `eq` or `=`, not `==`. The operator that tests numerical equality in POSIX shell scripts (`sh` is a POSIX-compliant shell) is `-eq` while the one that tests *string* equality is `=` and `==` isn't a thing.

So, if you want your script to be run by `sh`, change it to:

```
if [ 1 = 1 ]; then
    echo "Something"
fi
```

Which checks that the *string* `1` is the same as the *string* `1`, or to compare numerically, use:

```
if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Something"
fi
```

---

In addition, you have another problem. I can only reproduce the specific error you get in `dash` if I add a `\r` after the `then`. This is a classic problem when moving between Windows and Linux. While Linux uses `\n` as the line end character, Windows ends its lines with `\r\n`. This `\r` character is not visible to the user, but it is there and confuses the script. So, you can remove it with:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' ./test.sh
```

And in the future, use a proper text editor to write your scripts. Either one that works in the WSL system, or one that can at least be configured to not add `\r` to the ends of its lines.

Comment: However, this doesn't explain the error OP gets (dash says `foo.sh: 2: [: 1: unexpected operator`)

Comment: @muru no, I am assuming that's some strange foible of the `sh` in WSL.  Either way, the above solutions should fix the error.

Comment: I have used WSL a fair few times (usually for testing commands when on Windows), and I haven't yet found a significant difference in behaviour between the Linux commands there and on Ubuntu proper (not for the shells, anyway). I'd imagine something else, maybe Windows line endings or something like that.

Comment: @muru yeah, I thought of Windows line endings, but I passed the OP's script (which I assumed was directly pasted) through `od` and didn't see any. But you're right, adding a `\r` after `then` reproduces the error. Answer edited, thanks.

Comment: If it is \r , I would point out you should not currently be editing files for your linux environment from your windows environment - see - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

Comment: It is a CR. You can get the same error by opening a Bash shell and running `sh -c $'if [ 1 == 1 ]; then\r; echo "Something"\r; fi'`

Answer (score 2):

Let's keep it simple:

- `sh` is not `bash` on Ubuntu (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/976485/295286) for reference).
- `[` is a command, same as `test` command.  It doesn't support `==` for arithmetic comparison. Use `-eq` instead. This is one of utilities specified by [POSIX standards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), hence works in both `bash` and `dash`.

  ```
  if [ 1 -eq 1 ];
  then
      echo "it works!"
  fi
  ```
- `bash` has `((` which is called arithmetic expansion. This supports `==`. This feature is apparently borrowed from `ksh` shell.

  ```
  $ var=25 bash -c 'if((var==5)); then echo Y;else echo "N";fi'      
  N
  $ var=25 bash -c 'if((var==25)); then echo Y;else echo "N";fi' 
  Y
  ```
- Despite the fact that `dash` doesn't support `if (())`, in either shell `$((` will work because it is mandated by [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04). Taking only features that are common to both shells, we could do something like this while still using `==` for comparisons:

  ```
  $ var=25 dash -c 'if [ $((var==25)) -eq 1 ];then echo Y; else echo N;fi'
  Y
  $ var=25 dash -c 'if [ $((var==5)) -eq 1 ];then echo Y; else echo N;fi' 
  N
  ```
- We could throw away `if` statement altogether and use `case` instead(note that return status conforms to C, not shell behavior, i.e. true is 1 and false is 0, not the other way around as in shell):

  ```
  $ dash -c 'case $((1==1)) in 1) echo "equal";; 0) echo "not equal";;esac'                                                                                                
  equal
  $ dash -c 'case $((1==2)) in 1) echo "equal";; 0) echo "not equal";;esac'                                                                                                
  not equal
  ```
- or we can get sneaky with (ab)using arithmetic expansion:

  ```
  $ var=25 dash -c '_0(){ false;}; _1(){ true;}; if "_$((var==25))" ; then echo Y; else echo N; fi'
  ```

Comment: Since when is `(( ))` part of POSIX? `$(( ))` is, but there's nothing about `(( ))`.

Comment: @muru fixed that