# Space literal as function name in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, syntax

This question is loosely related to [one of my previous ones](https://askubuntu.com/q/977908/295286). TL;DR from [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/977910/295286) is that characters in function name have to be on [Portable Character Set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap06.html#tag_06_01) in order to be valid for a function name. Problem is that space *is* on the list (the `<space>` or `<U0020>` character), which is why I'm confused as to why I can't do this:

```
$ $'  '(){ echo "Hullo";}
bash: `'  '': not a valid identifier
$ hello$' 'world(){ echo "hi";}
bash: `hello' 'world': not a valid identifier
```

With other shells:

```
$ mksh -c  '\ (){ echo "Hello";} '                                                                                   
mksh:  : invalid function name

$ ksh -c  '\ (){ echo "Hello";} '                                                                                    
ksh:  : invalid function name

$ dash -c  '\ (){ echo "Hello";} '                                                                                   
dash: 1: Syntax error: Bad function name
```

Comment: As `mksh -c '1(){ …;}'` from your other question worked, did you try this with `mksh` too?

Comment: @dessert   OK, disregard my last comment. I've updated the question.  All shells I tested are consistently outputting error messages.   I also tried `mksh -c '1(){ …;}'` from last question  in interactive `mksh`,  which works, so that implies `mksh` being not entirely POSIX compliant in function declaration aspect. I wonder if that's something worth reporting to developers.

Comment: Nothing about it in the “Functions” section of [MirOS Manual: mksh](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/mksh.htm), however there's a POSIX mode you could try: `set -o posix` (see the hilarious FAQ at the end of the manual!)

Comment: @dessert nope, `1(){ echo "hi"; }` works even in posix mode :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me stress the relevant part:

> a word consisting **solely** of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set

Other characters in the portable character set are not allowed. Character being in the portable character set is [a necessary, but *not* sufficient, condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency).

Comment: Well, this is just slightly annoying that every word in the standard has to be interpreted.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy :D and yet your question is a perfect example of why they have to be so precise in their wording. You might find this to be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-lawyer/info

Comment: pity there's no such tag on AU