# Why there is no difference between / and ////// in bash path

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

```
ls -R /home/username/some/path
```

is the same as

```
ls - R /home///username/////////////some////path
```

Is there explanation for such interpretation of '`/`' character in bash?

I can't see implementation of ls program, but I can see my implementation of it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>


/* This program recursively prints files from given path. Should 
be equivalent to ls -R /given/path call from shell, except we 
don't concatenate '@' character at the end of symbolic link name, 
'/' if directory entry is directory, we don't sort output etc.. */

static void error_fatal (char *message);

static void traverse (char *filename);

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{

assert (argc == 2);

traverse (argv[1]);

exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

static void
traverse (char *filename)
{
struct stat stats;
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *entry;


  if (lstat (filename, &stats) < 0)
    error_fatal ("lstat");

  if (S_ISDIR (stats.st_mode))
{
    printf ("\n%s:\n", filename);

    if ((dir = opendir (filename)) == NULL)
      error_fatal ("opendir");

    if (chdir (filename) < 0)
      error_fatal ("chdir");

// In the first pass, we print all directory entries.

  while ((entry = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
    {
    if (!strcmp (entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp (entry->d_name, 
     ".."))
      continue;
    printf ("%s\t", entry->d_name);
}
  putchar ('\n');

  rewinddir (dir);

  // In the second pass, we examine if entry is directory, and if so, recursively call traverse() function.

  while ((entry = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
{
  if (!strcmp (entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp (entry->d_name, ".."))
    continue;

  if (lstat (entry->d_name, &stats) < 0)
    error_fatal ("lstat");

  if (S_ISDIR (stats.st_mode))
    {

      char *a;
      int size =
    sizeof (char) * (2 + strlen (filename) +
             strlen (entry->d_name));
      a = (char *) malloc (size);
      if (a == NULL)
    error_fatal ("malloc");
      if (getcwd (a, size) == NULL)
    error_fatal ("getcwd");
      strcat (a, "/");
      strcat (a, entry->d_name);
      traverse (a);
      free (a);
    }

}


  if (chdir ("..") < 0)
error_fatal ("chdir");

  closedir (dir);

}
}

static void
error_fatal (char *message)
{
  perror (message);
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

`uname -a` gives me:

```
Linux mk-Inspiron-5570 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:45:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`bash --version` gives me:

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason is simple: because it's a standard which isn't `bash` specific, but is specified by [POSIX standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), see [Definitions chapter, section 3.266 Pathname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266)

> Multiple successive slashes are considered to be the same as one slash.

These specifications are meant for portability and specify how Unix-like operating system and utilities should behave. `bash` has to support it if it wants to be used as `/bin/sh` shell, which on Ubuntu it actually used to be symlinked to `/bin/sh`. See also [What is the point of sh being linked to dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976485/what-is-the-point-of-sh-being-linked-to-dash)

Answer (score 2):

From the **The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition** -> Definitions -> [3.271 Pathname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271):

> A string that is used to identify a file. In the context of
>   POSIX.1-2017, a pathname may be limited to {PATH_MAX} bytes, including
>   the terminating null byte. It has optional beginning <slash>
>   characters, followed by zero or more filenames separated by
>   <slash> characters. A pathname can optionally contain one or
>   more trailing <slash> characters. **Multiple successive
>   <slash> characters are considered to be the same as one
>   <slash>, except for the case of exactly two leading
>   <slash> characters.**
>
> Note:
>       If a pathname consists of only bytes corresponding to characters from the portable filename character set (see Portable Filename
>   Character Set), <slash> characters, and a single terminating
>   <NUL> character, the pathname will be usable as a character
>   string in all supported locales; otherwise, the pathname might only be
>   a string (rather than a character string). Additionally, since the
>   single-byte encoding of the <slash> character is required to be
>   the same across all locales and to not occur within a multi-byte
>   character, references to a <slash> character within a pathname
>   are well-defined even when the pathname is not a character string.
>   However, this property does not necessarily hold for the remaining
>   characters within the portable filename character set.
>
> Pathname Resolution is defined in detail in Pathname Resolution.