# The simplest way to "subtrack" a string variable in terminal?

Tags: command-line

Let's assume that we've a variable `$test` which holds a value `asd 123` - what is the most simplest way to cut, for example, `asd` part?

I've googled this for awhile and surprised that I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bourne-like shells, such as `dash` ( [`/bin/sh` on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/976485) ), `bash` and `ksh` there is something known as [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02), and is a feature specified by POSIX standard.  Specifically, to quote `dash` manual:

```
 ${parameter%word}     Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then results in parameter, with the smallest
                       portion of the suffix matched by the pattern deleted.

 ${parameter%%word}    Remove Largest Suffix Pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then results in parameter, with the largest
                       portion of the suffix matched by the pattern deleted.

 ${parameter#word}     Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then results in parameter, with the smallest
                       portion of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted.

 ${parameter##word}    Remove Largest Prefix Pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then results in parameter, with the largest
                       portion of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted.
```

Thus, to replace `asd` part you can do:

```
$ var="asd 123"
$ echo ${var#asd*}
123
```

To remove `123` you can do:

```
$ echo ${var%*123}
asd
```

`bash` goes even further with this with another form: `${parameter/string/replacement}` and `${parameter//string/replacement}`. First one replaces first occurrence of string. Second form replaces all occurrences. For instance:

```
$ echo ${var//123/}
asd
$ echo ${var//asd/}
123
```

Note that according with the syntax, the `replacement` part is empty string