# Why 'xargs bash -c' is far slower than 'xargs sh -c'?

Tags: bash, sh, dash-shell

```
time seq 100 | xargs -i bash -c 'echo {}'
```

; 2.530s

```
time seq 100 | xargs -i sh -c 'echo {}'
```

; 0.223s

why?

PS: The title of mine for this post is more intuitive to be discovered or searched by google or any sort of search engines.

Comment: Related: [What is the point of sh being linked to dash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/976485/816190). Your actual question would be like: "Why bash is slower than sh"?

Comment: The short answer is because `sh` is symlink to `/bin/dash`, which is different from `/bin/bash`, and `/bin/sh` symlinked to `/bin/dash` exactly because  it's considerably faster shell