# Cron: no output file, but running without errors

Tags: cron, 19.10

I have Cron set up to with the following command:

```
* * * * * SHELL=/usr/bin/sh PATH=~/lectio-skema-til-.ics-kalender-master/script.sh
```

where `script.sh` has

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
cd /var/www/html/SECRET-PATH
wget "http://localhost:9002/?skole=518&elev=36015389032" -O kalender.ics
```

the command `wget "http://localhost:9002/?skole=518&elev=36015389032" -O kalender.ics` generates a `kalender.ics` file in `/var/www/html/SECRET-PATH`, and running the `script.sh` file works perfectly fine, however when running it with Cron, no files are generated in `/var/www/html/SECRET-PATH`.

I don't know what's wrong, because no errors are generated in the mail, and doing `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` doesn't have any errors either.

Comment: Does the shell pointed to by `/usr/bin/sh` exist? Please, change also the command `wget` to full path like this: `/usr/bin/wget`

Comment: Also the cron setup contains only variable declarations. No commands (scripts) to run. Also, replace the `~` with absolute path.

Comment: `PATH=~/lectio-skema-til-.ics-kalender-master/script.sh` will break the shell's search path for executables (including your `wget` command). Why are you doing that? In fact, why are you messing with`SHELL` and `PATH` at all?

Comment: It says, that cron does not alert: https://crontab.guru
crontab.guru - the cron schedule expression editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you run the specific script with your current user (let's say *your_user*), then the crontab entry for *your_user* should be something like this:

```
* * * * * /home/your_user/lectio-skema-til-.ics-kalender-master/script.sh
```

The script's first line indicates that an interpreter called `/usr/bin/sh` should be used. In my installation, there is no such executable. You should change to `/bin/bash` or (for a faster version) to `/bin/sh` [which is the *dash* shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976485/what-is-the-point-of-sh-being-linked-to-dash).

The script calls `wget` command. However, the PATH environment may not be set up correctly in your crontab. It is better to use full paths in commands. In my installation `wget` is at `/usr/bin/wget`. So, your script should be something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/html/SECRET-PATH
/usr/bin/wget "http://localhost:9002/?skole=518&elev=36015389032" -O kalender.ics
```

Comment: It works now, thank you! I added `home/username` to the script path, and made the script.sh a separate instruction afterwards, and added the changes in this answer too.