# Why can do some commands execute in terminal but not in script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm writing a basic script to practice working with arrays. When I run the script I get errors but when I run the same command in the terminal it executes.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a StringArray

StringArray=("blue" "green")

for  val in ${StringArray[@]}; do
    echo $val
done
```

I've given the script executable permission. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: If you have made the script executable then just run it with `./script.sh`. `sh script.sh` executes the script with the `sh` shell not the `bash` shell. They are two different command interpreters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the command `sh script.sh`, you try to run the script with `sh`. `sh` is symlinked to `dash`. `dash` is the standard command interpreter of Ubuntu. It is a different shell than `bash`, essentially with more minimal features, but very fast. Bash is much better for interactive use, so remains the default interpreter for the interactive prompt. Here is an excellent answer on the [difference between these command interpreters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976485/what-is-the-point-of-sh-being-linked-to-dash).

Instead, run your script with

```
bash script.sh
```

to have it executed under the proper shell.

If you place your script in a directory in your PATH and make it executable, you can run it at the command prompt merely by typing `script.sh`. At that moment, the shebang line, `#!/bin/bash` tells the system that `bash` should be used. When running the script as `bash script.sh` or `sh script.sh`, that shebang line is just a comment and not interpreted at all.