# is changing symlinks for "linux from scratch" harmful?

Tags: 20.04, symbolic-link, dash-shell, hard-link

I started [linux from scratch](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/read.html) for educational purpose. In preparing section it says:

```
Bash-3.2 (/bin/sh should be a symbolic or hard link to bash)

Bison-2.7 (/usr/bin/yacc should be a link to bison or small script that executes bison)

Gawk-4.0.1 (/usr/bin/awk should be a link to gawk)
```

At this moment links are like:

```
/bin/sh -> dash

/usr/bin/yacc -> /etc/alternatives/yacc

usr/bin/awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk
```

this in my ubuntu computer. Can it cause problems to change these links? And especially for `/bin/sh`. I couldn't understand what is dash.

Comment: If this is for educational purposes, do yourself a favour and perform the activities in a virtual machine. This will allow you to worry less about consequences and focus more on the meaning of the task.

Comment: Hello. If you want to know about dash do a man dash

Answer (score 1):

> is changing symlinks for "linux from scratch" harmful?

In general, an Ubuntu system has been set up and tested by the Ubuntu developers. Changing these symlinks means you are taking over system configuration. It depends how well the alternative tools you symlink to can replace the original tools. Anyhow, it is not recommended to change such configuration on a production system, but do not hesitate and have fun on a system intended for learning only.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1397336/558158) for some explanation about the `dash` command interpreter, and the difference with `bash`. Linking `sh` to `bash` will probably work well because `bash`, when invoked as `sh`, tries to mimic the startup behavior of the traditional Bourne Shell.

`bison` is available in the main repository, and when installed, it links (via the "alternatives" system) to a small script `/usr/bin/bison.yacc` that runs bison (Thanks to user mchid for the comment).

One can install `gawk` on an Ubuntu system, and use this for the `awk` command, but by default `mawk` is used because is smaller and much faster than `gawk`.

Ubuntu uses the Debian-alternatives system, which is why you some  symlinks pointing to items in `/etc/alternatives`. These, in turn, link back to the tool that is configured to be used. See [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) to learn about this system.

Comment: @mchid Thanks for letting this know. I do not on 21.10, but then this was a "minimal" install - maybe it comes with a full install as a dependency. Will update my answer.